# Touch screen, wacom, producing lines offscreen (Xournal et al)

Tags: virtualbox, tablet, touchscreen

I'm getting an error writing in Xournal that looks like this:

[image]

That is, whenever my pen touches the screen, it draws a line from upper left off-screen to the point where I connect.

I remember having a problem when I first installed Ubuntu on a tablet years ago, in like 2007, when the solution was much fiddling in xorg.conf, which I don't believe is even used anymore.  How can I fix this?  I'm running Ubuntu 13.10  in a virtualbox on a surface pro 2.

**UPDATE**

Seems to be confined to virtualbox, actually?  Trying to isolate the bug, I exported  my virtual machine and loaded it in VMWare Player.  There, I was able to use Xournal without this error.  (However, there I have a bunch of new errors I don't want, so I'd prefer a solution still for Virtualbox.)

**UPDATE 2**

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new machine and have the same problem.  This does not seem to be limited to either Xournal or virtualbox.  It occurs both virtualized and native.  Is this just generally a bug in ubuntu's wacom drivers?  Also, how would I be the lucky person to get this bug on 2 totally separate devices (on MS Surface Pro, one Lenovo X1) where no one else seems to get it at all?

**UPDATE 3**

Just got a notification I still had this up.  Intervening updates still haven't fixed this.  I basically just can't use the tablet function in Ubuntu.

Comment: Which version of xournal and which tablet? I am using xournal with a wacom cth-480 and, although it happens sometime to me too, it's really sporadic.

Comment: Xournal Version 4.7-1, tablet is Surface Pro 2.

Comment: Same than mine. Can't really help a lot... better trying to reach the developers via the mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/mailman/xournal-devel/. Development is quite slow but not stopped. Otherwise you can try xournal++ at https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/releases

Comment: This is a bug and can't be "answered" by us but developers.

Comment: What version on virtualbox you use?

Comment: I keep up to date with the virtualbox ppa, so whatever is in there.  (Changes pretty frequently and haven't noticed a difference.)